# roots of the equation $h(x)=1+2(x+1)^{2/x}-(2^{x+1}-1)^{2/x}$ for $x>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, normed-spaces

It is easy to note $h(1)=h(2)=0$.

It is evident from desmos that these are the only 2 solutions.
I came across this function while trying to verify parallelogram law:

$2 \Vert f \Vert^2 + 2\Vert g \Vert^2 = \Vert f + g \Vert^2 + \Vert f - g \Vert^2$
where $\Vert F \Vert=(\int_0^1|F|^p)^{1/p}$ with $f=x$ and $g=1$

Taking the derivative of $h(x)$ makes everything very messy to deal with.

How do I show there is only 2 root to $h(x)$ for $x>0$?

Comment: What is your initial problem ? I mean, why $h$ ?

Comment: @EDX $h(p)=\{2 \Vert x \Vert_p^2 + 2\Vert 1 \Vert_p^2 = \Vert x + 1 \Vert_p^2 + \Vert x - 1 \Vert_p^2\} * {g(p)}$ where $g(p)>0$ for all $p>0$. Hence $h(p)\ne0$ implies parallelogram law is not satisfied.

Comment: And what is $g(p)$ ?

Comment: @EDX $g(p)=(p+1)^{2/p}$